# Does the vSphere server need access to the SAN?

Tags: storage-area-network, vmware-vsphere

In the next few weeks we're doing a new VMWare/vSphere deployment, but the server that's been set aside for the vSphere server does **not** have access to the SAN that the VMWare blades will be using.

Is this a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VirtualCenter? Not an issue. It'll obtain SAN information via the hosts. The only non-ESX/ESXi box you might want to access your SAN is your backup host, if it's got a direct SAN backup option.